# ¿Cómo subir archivos de más de 5mb en IIS?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net

Dispongo de una subida de ficheros de tipo vídeo, el cual me guarda en el servidor los mismos por medio de una asincronía, pero en el momento que el vídeo es mas pesado de 5MB no me lo realiza (**No puede ser el límite ya que lo tengo asignado a 120MB**), he localizado el lugar del problema y es en el momento que asigno a la variable que tengo el `FormData()`, dejo el código de la operación:

### Javascript

---

```
//Funcion asincrona    
async function GuardarNuevoDocumento() {
    r1 = await GuardarDocumento();
    r2 = await GuardarTodo(r1);
}


function GuardarDocumento() {
  try {
    var tipo = $('#Tipo').val();
    var urlDoc = 'FuncionControlador';
    var campoDoc = 'idInput';

    
    var data = new FormData();
    var files = $("#" + campoDoc).get(0).files;
    if (files.length > 0) {
      //Si el archivo es mayor a 5 MB data continua siendo un 
      //FormData vacio, el append no lo realiza
      data.append("file", files[0]);       
    }

    var ajaxRequest = $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: urlDoc,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      data: data,
      success: function () {
        console.log("fin");
      },
      error: function(e){
        console.log(e);
      }
    });    
  } catch(e) {
        console.log(e)
  }
  return ajaxRequest;
}

 //ENVIAR AL CONTROLADOR
 function GuardarTodo(r1) {
   //Variables de otros inputs
   var nombre = $('#Nombre').val();
   var descripcion = $('#Descripcion').val();
   var tipo = $('#Tipo').val();
   //Declaro el archivo
   var documento = r1;

   if (documento == "") {
        //popup error
     avisos.error("Video", "El video no ha podido ser guardado");
   } else {
     //GUARDAR VIDEO(No es la función real, esta compilado de cabeza,
     //funciona bien la real)
     var data = [{"Nombre": nombre, "Descripcion":descripcion, "Tipo":tipo, "Documento": documento}]
     $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "URL",
       contentType: false,
       processData: false,
       data: data
     });    
   }
 }
```

### C#

---

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MultimediaUpload()
{
    try
    {
        var path = "";

        if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            path = PdfUpload(Request.Files[0], "RUTA");
        }

        return Content(path);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //LOG
        _log.Error(e);
        return null;
    }
}


public string PdfUpload(HttpPostedFileBase file, string ruta)
{
    if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
        string path = Path.Combine(ruta, fileName);
        file.SaveAs(path);
        return path;
    }
    else
        return null;
}
```

Ahora teniendo todo el código presente, se que al ser un archivo pesado necesito realizar alguna tarea para que se pause la ejecución de script hasta que se cargue dentro de data el archivo, he probado con:

```
data.append("file", files[0]).then(ajaxRequest);
```

y también con setTimeout, pero con esta, da igual el tiempo que le ponga que lo ejecuta linealmente y sin pausar.

> **¿Cómo puedo realizarlo para que independientemente del tamaño del vídeo lo asigne?**

Comment: ¿Qué límite es el que tienes en 120mb? ¿El máximo de subida de archivos o el máximo de recepción por POST o ambos? Luego, mientras se está subiendo el archivo, deshabilita botones y todo lo que no quieres que funcione en la página. Al terminar la subida (success), ahí lanzas la siguiente petición y reactivas todo lo que deshabilitaste.

Comment: en el `web.config` tengo `<requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="106954752"/>` no se si eso sirve para las dos cosas que dices

Comment: Probablemente también hay que modificar [`maxRequestLength`](https://webconnection.west-wind.com/docs/_4lp0zgm9d.htm)

Comment: Si es lo mismo que te he dicho que tengo

Comment: `<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="106954752"  executionTimeout="120" />`

Comment: vale, justo era eso, si quieres elaborar una respuesta te lo valido, si no, cierro la pregunta, gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Desconozco el funcionamiento de *IIS* y *.NET*, pero, teniendo en cuenta que:

En *PHP* se deben modificar dos variables en el archivo de configuración `php.ini`, una, para incrementar la cantidad de datos subidas por formulario `post_max_size` y otra para el tamaño máximo de archivos `upload_max_filesize`.

Y buscando un poco, encontré las opciones que deben modificarse en `web.config`:

```
<requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="106954752"/>

<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="106954752" executionTimeout="120" />
```

La primera limita el tamaño del buffer recibido por POST y, la segunda, el tamaño máximo de una petición en tiempo de ejecución que, a fin de cuentas, aplica para el envío del archivo.

Estas dos configuraciones deben establecerse directamente en número de bytes, en tu caso 106954752 / 1024 / 1024 = 102mb

**Atención:** Seguramente vas a tener que incrementar `executionTimeout` para evitar que la subida de archivos grandes expire; lamentablemente, no cuenta con la opción de poner en cero (como en *PHP*) para evitar límites, por lo que deberás realizar pruebas para determinar el valor final que vas a asignar, en segundos.