# ¿Modificar el MaxJsonLength para un método POST que recibe parámetros en el Body?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Tengo un Método POST en un Controlador de una aplicación desarrollada en MVC4, que se encarga de recibir un objeto por medio del FromBody desde una WebApi externa

```
[HttpPost]
public void UpdateFile([System.Web.Http.FromBody] ObjectFile File)
{
   ... codigo ...
}
```

la clase ObjectFile es así

```
public class ObjectFile 
    {       
        public string documento { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, string> metadata { get; set; }
    }
```

Donde *documento* es un archivo enviado en Base64, pero al momento de recibir un archivo de más de 2MB, sale la siguiente excepcion

```
Error durante la serialización o deserialización mediante JavaScriptSerializer de JSON. La longitud de la cadena supera el valor establecido en la propiedad maxJsonLength.

en System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(JavaScriptSerializer serializer, String input, Type type, Int32 depthLimit)
   en System.Web.Mvc.JsonValueProviderFactory.GetDeserializedObject(ControllerContext controllerContext)
   en System.Web.Mvc.JsonValueProviderFactory.GetValueProvider(ControllerContext controllerContext)
   en System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderFactoryCollection.<>c__DisplayClassc.<GetValueProvider>b__7(ValueProviderFactory factory)
   en System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   en System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   en System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   en System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   en System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderFactoryCollection.GetValueProvider(ControllerContext controllerContext)
   en System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.get_ValueProvider()
   en System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValue(ControllerContext controllerContext, ParameterDescriptor parameterDescriptor)
   en System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValues(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
   en System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState)
   en System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout)
   en System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.BeginInvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   en System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__17(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState)
   en System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout)
   en System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   en System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout)
   en System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   en System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   en System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__2(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState)
   en System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout)
   en System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   en System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   en System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)
   en System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   en System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
   en System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Ya trate de agregar la propiedad MaxJsonLength  en el Web.Config y no me funciono  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151987/can-i-set-an-unlimited-length-for-maxjsonlength-in-web-config/7207539#7207539

De igual forma agregue el siguiente atributo tomado de https://www.it-swarm-es.com/es/asp.net/puedo-establecer-una-longitud-ilimitada-para-maxjsonlength-en-web.config/967375227/ a mi método *UpdateFile* y no funciono

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class MaxJsonSizeAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    // Default: 10 MB worth of one byte chars
    private int maxLength = 10 * 1024 * 1024;

    public int MaxLength
    {
        set
        {
            if (value < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("value", "Value must be at least 0.");

            maxLength = value;
        }
        get { return maxLength; }
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        JsonResult json = filterContext.Result as JsonResult;
        if (json != null)
        {
            if (maxLength == 0)
            {
                json.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
            }
            else
            {
                json.MaxJsonLength = maxLength;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Espero obtener una ayuda de como poder modificar esto, o poder setear a nivel global la configuración del MaxJsonLength.

Comment: para hacerlo de manera global en el archivo **Web.Config** en la sección de **<appSettings>**  puedes agregar lo siguiente `<add key="aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers" value="999999999" />` o en **<system.web>**  agregar `<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="999999999" />`, espero te sirva de algo

Comment: una respuesta relacionada con el aumento del máximo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/388728/101499

Comment: @kllmp `<add key="aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers" value="999999999" />` agregue eso y también agregue diferentes opciones en el web.config, pero se ve que no lo toma; y tampoco me sirve  https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/388728/101499 porque lo mío es un objeto que se pasa en el body del post.

Comment: lo estas pasando por url? si es así tienes que buscar otra manera

Comment: Lo estoy pasando en el Body de la solicitud